# Problema con wordpress que no inicia por supuesto mantenimiento programado

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un problema con mi web. Estaba actualizando unos plugins y cambie de seccion en el panel. De repente quiero entrar nuevamente y me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

No disponible temporalmente por un mantenimiento programado. Vuelve a comprobarlo en unos minutos.

La pagina es xiaomimportperu.com

Answer (score 2):

Esta situación se da cuando una actualización no ha finalizado correctamente.

Comprueba si en raíz del sitio aparece un archivo `.maintenance`. De ser así, procede a eliminarlo y deberías poder entrar a tu site.